# Intel pin and chrono conflicts

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, intel-pin

I try to measure the runtime of the program using Intel Pin. For this purpose I include chrono in my project. However It is not going to compile well. It gives a lot of errors. Furthermore, I tried to include chrono to many standart Intel Pin examples - the same result.
Could you please help me to solve errors below?

```
ratio(24,32): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(25): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Abs<_Val>' being compiled
ratio(30,38): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(31): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Safe_mult<_Ax,_Bx,_Sfinae,_Good>' being compiled
ratio(40,36): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(41): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Sign_of<_Val>' being compiled
ratio(45,38): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(46): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Safe_addX<_Ax,_Bx,_Good,_Also_good>' being compiled
ratio(50,44): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ',', expected 'expression'
ratio(51): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Safe_addX<_Ax,_Bx,false,false>' being compiled
ratio(65,41): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(66): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_GcdX<_Ax,0>' being compiled
ratio(74,2): error C2504: 'integral_constant': base class undefined
ratio(74,38): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(158,5): error C2065: 'void_t': undeclared identifier
ratio(158,1): error C2226: syntax error: unexpected type 'std::_Ratio_multiply<_R1,_R2>::_Num::type'
ratio(159,1): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
ratio(159,1): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
ratio(159,58): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
ratio(159,58): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
ratio(186,35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(188): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::ratio_equal<_R1,_R2>' being compiled
ratio(195,39): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(197): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::ratio_not_equal<_R1,_R2>' being compiled
ratio(252,34): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(254): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::ratio_less<_R1,_R2>' being compiled
ratio(261,40): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(263): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::ratio_less_equal<_R1,_R2>' being compiled
ratio(279,43): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
ratio(282): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::ratio_greater_equal<_R1,_R2>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(512,39): error C2371: 'wint_t': redefinition; different basic types
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\crt\include\wchar.h(52): message : see declaration of 'wint_t'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(513,39): error C2371: 'wctype_t': redefinition; different basic types
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\crt\include\wchar.h(77): message : see declaration of 'wctype_t'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(538,19): error C2371: 'mbstate_t': redefinition; different basic types
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\crt\include\wchar.h(58): message : see declaration of 'mbstate_t'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\corecrt.h(552,28): error C2371: 'time_t': redefinition; different basic types
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\crt\include\sys\types.h(91): message : see declaration of 'time_t'
vcruntime_new.h(34,26): error C2011: 'std::nothrow_t': 'struct' type redefinition
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\libstdc++\include\new(10): message : see declaration of 'std::nothrow_t'
vcruntime_new.h(168,5): error C2084: function 'void *operator new(size_t,void *)' already has a body
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\libstdc++\include\new(36): message : see previous definition of 'new'
vcruntime_new.h(174,5): error C2084: function 'void operator delete(void *,void *) throw()' already has a body
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\libstdc++\include\new(40): message : see previous definition of 'delete'
vcruntime_new.h(184,5): error C2084: function 'void *operator new[](size_t,void *)' already has a body
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\libstdc++\include\new(37): message : see previous definition of 'new[]'
vcruntime_new.h(190,5): error C2084: function 'void operator delete[](void *,void *) throw()' already has a body
1>E:\Tools\source\pin\extras\libstdc++\include\new(41): message : see previous definition of 'delete[]'
xtimec.h(28,15): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
xtimec.h(28,19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
xtimec.h(30,15): error C2144: syntax error: 'long' should be preceded by ';'
xtimec.h(30,20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
xtimec.h(30,1): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP2': redefinition
xtimec.h(28): message : see declaration of '_CRTIMP2'
xtimec.h(31,15): error C2144: syntax error: 'long' should be preceded by ';'
xtimec.h(31,20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
xtimec.h(31,1): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP2': redefinition
xtimec.h(28): message : see declaration of '_CRTIMP2'
xtimec.h(32,15): error C2144: syntax error: '__int64' should be preceded by ';'
xtimec.h(32,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
xtimec.h(32,1): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP2': redefinition
xtimec.h(28): message : see declaration of '_CRTIMP2'
xtimec.h(36,15): error C2144: syntax error: '__int64' should be preceded by ';'
xtimec.h(36,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
xtimec.h(36,1): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP2': redefinition
xtimec.h(28): message : see declaration of '_CRTIMP2'
xtimec.h(37,15): error C2144: syntax error: '__int64' should be preceded by ';'
xtimec.h(37,25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
xtimec.h(37,1): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP2': redefinition
xtimec.h(28): message : see declaration of '_CRTIMP2'
chrono(28,55): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
chrono(29): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::treat_as_floating_point<_Rep>' being compiled
chrono(96,43): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
chrono(171): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>' being compiled
chrono(96,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
chrono(96,30): error C2126: 'std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>::common_type_t' cannot be declared with 'constexpr' specifier
chrono(96,1): warning C4869: 'nodiscard' may only be applied to classes, enumerations, and functions
chrono(97,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
chrono(101,43): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
chrono(101,1): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
chrono(101,30): error C2126: 'std::chrono::duration<_Rep,_Period>::common_type_t' cannot be declared with 'constexpr' specifier
chrono(101,1): warning C4869: 'nodiscard' may only be applied to classes, enumerations, and functions
chrono(102,1): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
chrono(223,24): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
chrono(224): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Lcm<_Ax,_Bx>' being compiled
chrono(228,19): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
chrono(228,19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
chrono(228,19): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
chrono(228,37): error C2065: '_Rep1': undeclared identifier
chrono(228,44): error C2065: '_Period1': undeclared identifier
chrono(228,28): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(228,28): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(229,22): error C2065: '_Rep2': undeclared identifier
chrono(229,29): error C2065: '_Period2': undeclared identifier
chrono(229,13): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(229,13): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(229,40): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
chrono(229,40): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
chrono(235,8): error C2976: 'std::common_type': too few template arguments
chrono(228): message : see declaration of 'std::common_type'
chrono(238,2): error C2976: 'std::common_type': too few template arguments
chrono(236): message : see declaration of 'std::common_type'
chrono(243,39): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
chrono(243,39): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
chrono(243,16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
chrono(243,39): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
chrono(243,49): error C2065: '_Rep1': undeclared identifier
chrono(243,56): error C2065: '_Period1': undeclared identifier
chrono(243,40): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(243,40): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(243,76): error C2065: '_Rep2': undeclared identifier
chrono(243,83): error C2065: '_Period2': undeclared identifier
chrono(243,67): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(243,67): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(244,34): error C2065: '_Rep1': undeclared identifier
chrono(244,41): error C2065: '_Period1': undeclared identifier
chrono(244,25): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(244,25): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(244,74): error C2065: '_Rep2': undeclared identifier
chrono(244,81): error C2065: '_Period2': undeclared identifier
chrono(244,65): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(244,65): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(245,81): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
chrono(245,81): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
chrono(251,39): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
chrono(251,39): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
chrono(251,16): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
chrono(251,26): error C2374: 'std::chrono::common_type_t': redefinition; multiple initialization
chrono(243): message : see declaration of 'std::chrono::common_type_t'
chrono(251,39): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
chrono(251,49): error C2065: '_Rep1': undeclared identifier
chrono(251,56): error C2065: '_Period1': undeclared identifier
chrono(251,40): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(251,40): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(251,76): error C2065: '_Rep2': undeclared identifier
chrono(251,83): error C2065: '_Period2': undeclared identifier
chrono(251,67): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(251,67): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period2' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(252,34): error C2065: '_Rep1': undeclared identifier
chrono(252,41): error C2065: '_Period1': undeclared identifier
chrono(252,25): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Rep1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Rep'
chrono(252,25): error C2923: 'std::chrono::duration': '_Period1' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Period'
chrono(252,74): error C2065: '_Rep2': undeclared identifier
chrono(252,81): error C2065: '_Period2': undeclared identifier
chrono(252,1): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
```

Comment: Just tested it - yepp... just doing `#include <chrono>` and nothing else breaks the build.

Comment: Intel Pin comes with its own CRT which does not support C++11.

Comment: So, is there anyway to fix it? It seems not only chrono- bugs, but also including filesystem and other modules suffer.

Comment: Newer Pin versions should support C++11 - which version of pin are you using?

Comment: Pin: pin-3.13-98189-60a6ef199

Comment: Please include a minimal repro: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example